# Editing excel from VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, excel, vba

I need some pointers about applying multiple edit options in a single cell in excel from VB.NET

I have an excel document in which I need to enter three lines of text in a single cell.
These three lines will be saved as a single text with breaks in the database.
I have fetched the text from the database and applied it in Excel but the three lines of that text in a single cell have three different kinds of formatting.

For Eg:
- First line needs to be bold and pink color and in
- second line some letters need to be in bold and in blue color and
- third line as black with no formatting.

How do I apply these three kinds of formatting programatically to a three lined single text fetched from database?

Is there a way to do it in VB.NET itself or can I make some other bypass coding so that the text will be formatted after inserting in Excel or that I modify the text in database so it will recognize the formatting when inserting?

Here's the code I have sofar:

```
wk = ex.Workbooks.Open("TEST.xls") st = wk.Worksheets(1) 
st.Cells(row, 3) = reader.GetValue(5).ToString()
```

Comment: Please, post the code you have written so far (the one communicating VB.NET with Excel)

Comment: Record a macro in Excel to format the three lines and then simply port it to vb.net :)

Comment: Whitespace is your friend... Having the question in one big blob makes it very hard and uninviting to read....

Comment: You need to put the code in the question :-), not the comments.

Comment: This is my code   `                                               query_strg = "Select TEXT from DB1"
rs = New SqlCommand(query_strg, srv_conn)
reader = rs.ExecuteReader()
reader.Read()     wk = ex.Workbooks.Open("TEST.xls")                                         st = wk.Worksheets(1)                                                      st.Cells(row, col) = reader.GetValue(0).ToString()` Now the text that i have pasted in excel cell has three lines and each line needs to be formatted with different and different category.

Comment: In the question, not the comments..., edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, record a macro in Excel and then port that code over to VB.net.

So here's the recording:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "line1, line2, line3"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=5).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=8, Length:=5).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=13, Length:=7).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
End Sub
```

Now simply port that code over to VB.net and you're done.

Only thing you need to determine if where the formatting starts.
For that you'll need to search the end-of-line char.

Comment: How to do it. I recorded the macro but when i run the codes in VB.NET it throws exception. What are the changes that needs to be done for executing the macro code in VB.NET

Comment: I recorded a macro in excel and executed it from VB.NET for the needed scenario but now i need to delete that macro when saving the excel from VB.NET... How to delete a macro from VB.NET?

Comment: No you need to **port** the code to VB.net, not execute an excel macro remotely.

Comment: The macro codes are not being executed in VB.NET... How to make macro code execute in VB.NET

Comment: You need to **write** them in VB.net, using the VBA as a template.

Comment: OK. Can you give me an example by writing VB.Net code for above macro.

Comment: No, you'll have to work at that yourself. It's really quite a simple translation.